# Overriding or extending a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie to jquery so please excuse me if my terminology is off, but I want to override or extend a function (not sure what the proper term is).

The lead developer in our department created a jquery .js file that we source into every one of our pages.  There is a function in it that looks like this:

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    //DO SOME STUFF HERE
 });
```

This gets executed when the user closes the browser window.  I have some additional functionality that I want to perform (on my own page) when the user closes the browser window, but I still want to perform the code that is in the function that our lead developer created.

How can I have the lead developer's code and my own code both executed when the window is closed?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can bind as many event handlers to an event as you wish, simply ensure that one of them does not return false or stop the propagation and you should be good.

Comment: I need to make sure that my code gets executed before his code.  How can I do that?  If I bind another event handler, how can I be sure mine goes off first?

Comment: It would need to be ahead of that other one in the call stack/sequence of the page script - similar to how you put the jQuery core ahead of your client code.

Comment: Interesting.  We are using a ASP.NET master page file which already has jquery and his file sourced in already.  So by default, mine comes after his.